# How to avoid indexing or indexing canonical urls in sitemap.xml

Tags: wordpress, seo

I am running a WordPress site and choosing `http:://domain.com` as my preferred domain in WordPress settings and also in google web master tools too. But I can see that lot of canonical urls added in my sitemap.xml that I created using **Yoast SEO** plugin.

Is there any way to adding canonical urls ( `http:://www.mydomain.com` ) in sitemap.xml ?

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

Install and activate one of the popular SEO plugins, such as All in One SEO Pack or yoast.

Once activated, navigate to the settings and ensure that the “Canonical URLs” checkbox is selected: [image]

That’s all you need to do! If you view the source of one of your site’s pages, you will spot the following tag nestled near the top:
[image]

The above code is the best way of informing Google what the canonical URL is for a specific page, and All in One SEO Pack will repeat this code for every page on your site.

**Reference link**
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-canonicalization-guide/

In case of yoast plugin :

https://kb.yoast.com/kb/canonical-urls-in-wordpress-seo/

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer Vasim - but I am afraid that you did not get what I mean . Let me explain- I already added canonical - but the issue is - in my sitemap.xml I can see both urls . So I am getting seo warning like " Indexable pages missing in the sitemap.xml " please advice a solution